# What SAAS call center system can handle one time passcodes?

Tags: software-development

I want to give our users a one-time passcode with which to contact us on the phone. This code would be generated on our site and be instantly given to the customer after he enters his phone number and is validated via API against our database.

The customer would then call in with this passcode and enter it into the IVR. Depending on the settings, this would prioritize the call based on the one time pass or give access / deny the call.

What SAAS call center software would allow me to utilize one time passcodes? Either as a native feature, custom module, or through some type of API implementation. If not a native feature, how much custom development on the SAAS call center end would be required to do this?